# Getting started with osmdroid, mapview shows only grid

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I am planning to use OSM in my android app and i decided to give osmdroid a try. Here is what i have done till now.

1: I downloaded the slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar and osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar and copied them to my libs folder and added them to build path.

2: My Xml layout file code looks like this.

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

3: I have added all the permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

4: My on create method looks like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapify);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
    }
```

My problem is that despite the code running fine i am not able to see the map when i run on my emulator. I am connected to internet and am able to see maps while using google map view.
I have look around the internet and also some questions in stackoverflow regarding same issue. Most of them either seem to have forgotten to add permissions or to add slf4j to build path. I have done both so i am at loss at what have i done wrong. Would be very grateful if you provided some insight.

Solved:

I don't know what is the reason but the map displays after i relaunch it a few times. After that everything seems to work fine. This happens again when i try in new virtual device. When i close and relaunch the app few times it starts working fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, the fact is that i successfully made it work and from one day to another without any code change it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case somebody needs the answer. This may be caused if the emulator does not have an external storage to cache map tiles. I created an emulator with SD card and that solved the problem
[open street maps (osmdroid) shows grey tiles not map in PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655064/open-street-maps-osmdroid-shows-grey-tiles-not-map-in-pc)

Answer (score 0):

As said in documentation you have to call

```
`Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx))`
```

as this might be depracated now but it solves the problem