# open street maps (osmdroid) shows grey tiles not map in PC

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid to get open Street maps in my app. I had build my project with the needed jars (osmdroid) and added all needed permissions in the manifest. But when I try to debug my app in android emulator (adt eclipse) I am not able to see the map, only grey tiles. 
My project is working fine because if I debug in a smartphone I am able to see the map, the problem is only with the emulator.

I have done some research but I only found information of google maps solutions but not open street maps (osmdroid).
Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

this is how I show the map in xml file

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="322dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>
```

this is my main activity

```
mapView  = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
```

These are my permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

and the jars added to my build path

```
osmdroid-android-4.2.jar
osmdroid-thrid-party-4-2.jar
slf4j-1.7.7.jar
```

Comment: Props for using OSM rather than Google! A lot of issues on their GitHub page seem to regard Maven. Are you using Maven in your project?

Comment: Does the emulator have a network connection?

Comment: yes it does, I have even added a proxy to the emulator if that was the problem, but I am still experimenting this problem

Comment: Can you access the Internet via the web browser on the emulator?

Comment: Yes I do. I am sure it is not a network connection problem

Comment: Could your problem be the same as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060389/osmdroid-displays-an-empty-grid

Comment: actually @Paul-Jan , that was my problem. I added a SD card to my emulator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created an emulator with SD card and that solved the problem